# Can a Pakistani citizen with a CR1 US visa apply for the Turkish e-Visa?

Tags: visas, turkey, pakistani-citizens, e-visas

My wife and I plan to visit Turkey for a few days towards the end of March. She has a Pakistani Passport with a US CR1 visa (which she got through me being the US Citizen sponsor). I believe I'll be able to get a Turkish E-visa.

Now I wanted to ask is she eligible to get a Turkish E-Visa? I've heard that the CR1 visa is a valid visa, but is not "endorsed" unless the visa holder goes through a US point-of-entry. Will this create issues for her to get the E-Visa? Moreover, her CR1 visa expires in May, so I also wanted to ask whether this could also create issues?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to apply for a normal visa for your wife, but it should be issued without issues.

You will need to apply for an e-visa though; and it will be granted immediately online.

Your only issue will be trying to find an appointment slot in time for your flight.

In Kuwait, the visa is issued on the same day as your appointment.

Comment: Pakistan passport holder are eligible for evisas if they have: (Valid visa OR valid residence permit from one of the Schengen Countries, USA, UK or Ireland)

Comment: It has to be stamped and can't be an e-visa, so it fails the requirement.